# jsFiddle custom DTD

Tags: javascript, html, doctype, dtd, jsfiddle

when playing with my project i need to debug it, and i like the system of jsFiddle, so i'm developing on it directly

Problem is I have XML with Element named `link` which is completely different from HTML's link

When I try to parse it via javascript, it tells me that `link` doesn't have any childnodes because of HTML DTD used (no matter which i select)

I tried adding
`<?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE rootElement [ .. dtd declarations.. ]>`
to top of code, but this won't help

Is it possible to use jsFiddle with own DTD or not? if it is, how can i achieve this?

Thanks

**code sample**

```
<wrap>
    <link attribute=value>
        <child_node></child_node>
    </link>
</wrap>
```

when I use

```
var wrap = document.getElementsByTagName("wrap");
wrap = wrap[0];
var lnk = wrap.getElementsByTagName("link");
lnk = lnk[0];
document.write(lnk.getElementsByTagName("child_node"));
```

where `wrap` and `link` are objects of `HTMLElement`
it will show empty array
but those childs are accessible through `childNodes` property

Comment: I solved my problems by prefixing all elements name with "something_" so it won't collide with elements specified in HTML5, which is default DTD of JsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to check if dtd accepts secondary declarations, in my opinion it would parse the page the way you put it, to show the exact results.